# Is there some online chess board where you can teach a kid how to play?

Tags: learning, online-chess, chessboards

A family friend wants to teach her grandchild how to play chess. The problem is that, due to the pandemic, they live apart from each other, so she has to do this online. Is there some website where the players can set up the board by themselves and only then start playing i.e. a website where you start the game as you would if you were playing OTB, which is by first setting up the board?

I am aware of Lichess' board editor (https://lichess.org/editor), which can be tweaked to work in the specific case from above (the kid can clear the board, set up the pieces by himself, send the invite link and then they may play), but I wonder if there is some better resource that I don't know of.

Answer (score 3):

The websites lichess.com and apronus.com are your best options to chose from. They both do the same thing, but I suggest you use [apronus.com.](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/)

You can set up the board by yourself, send an invite link, and do other things just like you want.